# How can I compile GCC natively on Android?

Tags: android, linux, gcc, sh

I have been trying to compile GCC natively on Android using a terminal emulator (termux), but since this does not store its binaries in /bin as a normal Linux PC I get the following error:

```
./configure: /bin/sh: Bad interpreter: No such file or directory.
```

I was thinking that in order to fix this I could symlink termux's sh to a directory named bin in the phone's root filesystem. However when I attempted to create /bin (even as a superuser) I got the following error as well:`Error: Read only file system.` How can I fix this?

Before you ask:

- I Know about the NDK, but I want to compile it natively.
- I do have GCC and all the dependencies installed.
- Yes I am rooted and have tried to create /bin as root.

Comment: Some what related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13163/how-can-i-compile-native-applications-on-my-rooted-phone I'm curious as to why on Android vs building ARM binary on a more full feature Linux platform like Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I want to do it in Android because I have a spare Galaxy S6 which is far more powerful than Raspberry Pi and it's more portable as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear nowadays that this has already done.
From your termux terminal type;

```
apt update; apt --assume-yes upgrade; apt --assume-yes install coreutils gnupg wget tsu
mkdir -p $PREFIX/etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://its-pointless.github.io/files/ termux extras" > $PREFIX/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pointless.list
wget https://its-pointless.github.io/pointless.gpg
apt-key add pointless.gpg
apt update
apt install gcc-8
```

Or download and run this script.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/its-pointless/gcc_termux/master/setup-pointless-repo.sh